# Regular expression for api endpoint pattern check

Tags: regex

I am looking for a generic regular expression to check api endpoint pattern.

Requirements -

1. It should allow one or multiple /
2. It should allow { and }
3. String inside // or {} will be camel Case only

example -
/acbAbf023/{acfAbc12}/asp/avbTfg/abd01

Thanks in advance for your help.

I have tried below which doesn't allow camel case
^[a-z0-9/{}]+$

Below is for camel case
^[a-z]+[1-9]?([A-Z][a-z1-9]+)*$

Not sure how to combine both for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try

```
^\/({*([a-z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9{}]*)?}*\/?)+$
```

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gG45iu/1)

- `^\/`: start of string match a slash `/`
- `({*([a-z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9{}]*)?}*\/?)+` match the group `{*([a-z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9{}]*)?}*\/?` one or multiple time (`+`) to make sure it match the entire url path

  - `{*` match `{` none or multiple times (`*`)
  - `([a-z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9{}]*)?` match the group `[a-z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9{}]*` 0 or 1 time (`?`) (for empty url like `//` or `/{}/`)

    - `[a-z0-9]+` match the first character as lowercase or number (to ensure camelCase) one or multiple times
    - `[a-zA-Z0-9{}]*` match any word character in range a-z, both lowercase and uppercase, number and curly braces none or multiple times (`*`)

**Note**: this regex doesn't ensure the brackets are open and close properly

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the pattern that you have tried, assuming the camel case should start with a lowercase character, you might use:

```
^(?:\/(?:[a-z0-9]+(?:[A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*|{[a-z0-9]+(?:[A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*}))+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `\/(?:[a-z0-9]+` Match `/` and 1+ chars a-z0-9
  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

    - `[A-Z][a-z0-9]+` Match a char A-Z and 1+ times a char a-z0-9
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
  - `|` Or
  - `{[a-z0-9]+(?:[A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*}` Match the same pattern as above between `{...}`
  - `)` Close the non capture group
- `)+` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MzUXin/1)